# SCM Git option overridden in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Probably unusual behavior. Whenever i save the Git configuration, it is not saved and overridden to none that's why my build is failing. I have also updated the plugin, restarted the Jenkins but still same issue. Every time i select Git option and provide repo details, it goes to None option again and build logs says, no directory found. Help will be highly appreciated. See my configuration below.

[image]

[image]

[image]